# Алгоритм работы банкомата

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Программный продукт имитирует работу банкомата. В наличии есть 10 купюр по 100 грн, 5 по 50 грн и 15 по 20 грн. Пользователь вводит целое число `X` — сумму которую желает снять. Программа должна вывести количество каждого вида купюр, которые должен выдать банкомат, если это возможно. Я уже создал форму и подписался на событие `KeyPress` текстбокса (чтобы разрешить вводить только цифры). Меня интересует именно тот вопрос как мне сделать, чтобы программа выводила количество купюр каждого вида которые должен выдать банкомат по условиям моей задачи.

Comment: А как пробовали? Целочисленно разделить X на 100, сколько получилось — столько надо выдать купюр достоинством 100 (если столько есть в наличии), сколько осталось — выдаём более мелкими купюрами по тому же принципу

Comment: Тоесть мне надо создать переменную которая будет иметь в себе все числа от минимума до максимума и просто делить потом ту переменную на 100 если есть остачя то дальше на 50 ну и в конце на 20 если так то у меня новый вопрос а как решить проблему если программа будет неправильно определять количество купюр от например я введу 1500 как сказать программе что сюда нужно 10 купюр по 100 , 4 по 5о и 5 по 20 к примеру.

Answer (score 2):

Начните, например, с такого алгоритма:

```
var banknotes = new Dictionary<int, int>
{
    [100] = 10,
    [50] = 5,
    [20] = 15
};
Console.Write("Введите сумму: ");
var amount = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
var toIssue = new Dictionary<int, int>();
var left = amount;
foreach (var nominal in banknotes.Keys.OrderByDescending(x => x))
{
    var count = Math.Min(left / nominal, banknotes[nominal]);
    toIssue[nominal] = count;
    left -= count * nominal;
}
if (left > 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Невозможно выдать введенную сумму!");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Выдаем:");
    foreach (var nominal in toIssue.Keys.OrderByDescending(x => x))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Купюр номиналом {nominal} — {toIssue[nominal]} штук");
        banknotes[nominal] -= toIssue[nominal];
    }
}
```

Этот код будет работать неправильно в некоторых ситуациях, например, если введено 1500 (можно выдать как `10*100+4*50+15*20`, но программа скажет что нельзя), или 110 (еще более сложный случай, можно выдать как `50+3*20`), доработайте алгоритм самостоятельно

Comment: Доработка будет нетривиальная, бэктрекинг и все такое

Comment: @VladD, согласен, об этом написано под кодом, этот алгоритм по сути работает только для идеального случая, когда у нас есть бесконечное количество всевозможных купюр, в том числе достоинством `1`

Comment: У кого есть желание и время — может написать хороший настоящий алгоритм, решающий задачу, метку [алгоритм] навесил, для привлечения тех, кто на ней обитает :)

Comment: @VladD, с бэктрекингом, боюсь, до полного перебора недалеко. Думаю, как-то можно завязаться на тот факт, что 50 не делится нацело на 20 (дает остаток 10) и поэтому надо комбинировать именно их. Для купюрного ряда где каждый следующий номинал делится нацело на предыдущий алгоритм сработает.

Comment: Да, для такого алгоритма вроде бы нужно чтобы НОД всех чисел присутствовал в списке (например, 1).  А так вообще похоже на задачу упаковки ранца.

Comment: [Ну как бы вот](https://informatics.mccme.ru/mod/book/view.php?id=815).

Comment: @aepot, в ваших руках возможность написать ответ рядом, с меня плюсик

Comment: @АндрейNOP я больше склогяюсь к тому, что автору вопроса надо проверить, сняли ли с него бан в гугле, и если да, то воспользоваться поиском. Потому что задача суперпопсовая. Я ее еще в школе на информатике решал. А ваш ответ хороший. К тому же автор не показал попытку решить задачу, а решать за него полностью - не формат для StackOverflow. По последней причине я не могу воткнуть сюда плюсик. :)

Comment: @aepot, ошибаетесь, готовые решения — именно что ни на есть формат SO, ну и, собственно, идея в том, чтобы из гугла приходили как раз на SO. Это с точки зрения самого SO, конечно, вы, как автор, вправе решать для себя что для вас приемлемо, что нет, на что отвечать, на что — нет

Comment: Так я так и делаю, и не имею возражений против вашего подхода. :)